# USE WMI and WMQ to get Logical Disk and Partition Information from Win32_PnPEntity of SERVICE type USBSTOR

Tags: usb, wmi, hardware, wmi-query, disk-partitioning

I am detecting when our proprietary USB device is attached to a PC.  When we detect this, we get the related **Win32_PnPEntity**.  We want to use this **Win32_PnPEntity** as a source of the following information:
- USB Descriptor VID, PID, REV, Firmware Version.
- Logical Disk Drive Volume and Partition information to get Drive Letter information.

The problem I am having is trying to figure out how to use WMI and WMQ to get to the Logical Disk and partition information from the **Win32_PnPEntity**.
The **Win32_PnPEntity** is of **Service** type **USBSTOR** (USB Storage I think?)

Following is a description of the process I currently go through:

I listen to the **Win32_USBControllerDevice** with the event watcher so as to detect when the USB Device is attached or detached from the PC.  I use the following query to constrain what comes through on the event:

> "SELECT * FROM
>   __InstanceOperationEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE TargetInstance ISA
>   'Win32_USBControllerDevice' AND
>   TargetInstance.__RELPATH LIKE '%DeviceId=%VID_1111%'"

When this event comes through I pull the "**Win32_USBControllerDevice.Dependent**" property and pull out the "**DeviceId**" value.  I then use this "**DeviceId**" value with the **Win32_PNPEntity** class to get the associated instance.

This is where things get tricky for me...

I need to get to the **Win32_DiskDrive** that the **Win32_PnPEntity** instance relates to.  I need this instance so as to get to the volume information, so I can get the drive letter each partition is assigned.  But I have no idea on how to get to it.

I go through this process as the **Win32_PnPEntity** provides the VID, PID for constraint on event listening and searching... but it also provides the Firmware Version which I need.  So from this point I want to get the **Win32_DiskDrive** for the **Win32_PnPEntity**.

Any input would be appreciated.

--- EXTRA INFORMATION TO BETTER DESCRIBE THE ISSUE:

The steps I have got working so far are as follows:
- Listen to the '__InstanceModificaitionEvent' for the 'Win32_USBControllerDevice'
- Get the 'Win32_PnPEntity' from the 'TargetInstnace' of the '__InstanceModificaitionEvent'
- Get the 'DeviceId' from the 'Win32_PnPEntity' which contains the PID, VID information.

The issue I have now is trying to find the 'Win32_LogicalDisk' AND/OR 'Win32_DiskDrive' AND/OR 'Win32_DiskPartition' OR some other ASSOCIATOR or REFERENCES link to the drive letter the USB device attached has been assigned for the 'Mass Storge' instance.

The best way I can think of the issue is described in the following 'diagram':

```
           USB DEVICE  
          |         |  
----------|         |----  
| Win32_DiskDrive       | Win32_PnPEntity
```

What I am trying to do, is figure out how to get from the 'Win32_PnPEntity' representation of the USB Device to the 'Win32_DiskDrive' representation.

Following is a powershell script I run, while the device is attached.  It gives me all the instances that belong to the USB Device.  I know they belong to the one device as I have attached only one of the devices and with our custom editing of the USB DESCRIPTOR I know what to expect.

---

PS C:\Users\USER.DOMAIN> gwmi Win32_PNPEntity |? { ($_.DeviceId -match 'VEN_MYCOMPANY&') -or ($_.DeviceId -match 'VID_XXXX')}

__GENUS                     : 2
__CLASS                     : Win32_PnPEntity
__SUPERCLASS                : CIM_LogicalDevice
__DYNASTY                   : CIM_ManagedSystemElement
__RELPATH                   : Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="USB\VID_XXXX&PID_0001\YYYY"
__PROPERTY_COUNT            : 24
__DERIVATION                : {CIM_LogicalDevice, CIM_LogicalElement, CIM_ManagedSystemElement}
__SERVER                    : BYDEFAULT
__NAMESPACE                 : root\cimv2
__PATH                      : \BYDEFAULT\root\cimv2:Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="USB\VID_XXXX&PID_0001\YYYY"
Availability                :
Caption                     : USB Mass Storage Device
ClassGuid                   : {36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000}
CompatibleID                : {USB\Class_08&SubClass_06&Prot_50, USB\Class_08&SubClass_06, USB\Class_08}
ConfigManagerErrorCode      : 0
ConfigManagerUserConfig     : False
CreationClassName           : Win32_PnPEntity
Description                 : USB Mass Storage Device
DeviceID                    : USB\VID_XXXX&PID_0001\YYYY
ErrorCleared                :
ErrorDescription            :
HardwareID                  : {USB\VID_XXXX&PID_0001&REV_0001, USB\VID_XXXX&PID_0001}
InstallDate                 :
LastErrorCode               :
Manufacturer                : Compatible USB storage device
Name                        : USB Mass Storage Device
PNPDeviceID                 : USB\VID_XXXX&PID_0001\YYYY
PowerManagementCapabilities :
PowerManagementSupported    :
Service                     : USBSTOR
Status                      : OK
StatusInfo                  :
SystemCreationClassName     : Win32_ComputerSystem
SystemName                  : BYDEFAULT

__GENUS                     : 2
__CLASS                     : Win32_PnPEntity
__SUPERCLASS                : CIM_LogicalDevice
__DYNASTY                   : CIM_ManagedSystemElement
__RELPATH                   : Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="WPDBUSENUMROOT\UMB\2&37C186B&0&STORAGE#VOLUME#_??_USBSTOR#DISK&VEN_MYCOMPANY&PROD_ZZZZ_-_STORAGE&REV_5678#YYYY&0#"
__PROPERTY_COUNT            : 24
__DERIVATION                : {CIM_LogicalDevice, CIM_LogicalElement, CIM_ManagedSystemElement}
__SERVER                    : BYDEFAULT
__NAMESPACE                 : root\cimv2
__PATH                      : \BYDEFAULT\root\cimv2:Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="WPDBUSENUMROOT\UMB\2&37C186B&0&STORAGE#VOLUME#_??_USBSTOR#DISK&VEN_MYCOMPANYI&PROD_ZZZZ_-_STORAGE&REV_5678#YYYY&0#"
Availability                :
Caption                     : ZZZZ
ClassGuid                   : {eec5ad98-8080-425f-922a-dabf3de3f69a}
CompatibleID                : {wpdbusenum\fs}
ConfigManagerErrorCode      : 10
ConfigManagerUserConfig     : False
CreationClassName           : Win32_PnPEntity
Description                 : MYCOMPANY - Storage
DeviceID                    : WPDBUSENUMROOT\UMB\2&37C186B&0&STORAGE#VOLUME#_??_USBSTOR#DISK&VEN_MYCOMPANY&PROD_ZZZZ_-_STORAGE&REV_5678#YYYY&0#
ErrorCleared                :
ErrorDescription            :
HardwareID                  :
InstallDate                 :
LastErrorCode               :
Manufacturer                : MYCOMPANY
Name                        : ZZZZ
PNPDeviceID                 : WPDBUSENUMROOT\UMB\2&37C186B&0&STORAGE#VOLUME#_??_USBSTOR#DISK&VEN_MYCOMPANY&PROD_ZZZZ_-_STORAGE&REV_5678#YYYY&0#
PowerManagementCapabilities :
PowerManagementSupported    :
Service                     : WUDFRd
Status                      : Error
StatusInfo                  :
SystemCreationClassName     : Win32_ComputerSystem
SystemName                  : BYDEFAULT

__GENUS                     : 2
__CLASS                     : Win32_PnPEntity
__SUPERCLASS                : CIM_LogicalDevice
__DYNASTY                   : CIM_ManagedSystemElement
__RELPATH                   : Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="STORAGE\VOLUME\_??_USBSTOR#DISK&VEN_MYCOMPANY&PROD_ZZZZ_-_STORAGE&REV_5678#YYYY&0#{53F56307-B6BF-11D0-94F2-00A0C91EFB8B}"
__PROPERTY_COUNT            : 24
__DERIVATION                : {CIM_LogicalDevice, CIM_LogicalElement, CIM_ManagedSystemElement}
__SERVER                    : BYDEFAULT
__NAMESPACE                 : root\cimv2
__PATH                      : \BYDEFAULT\root\cimv2:Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="STORAGE\VOLUME\_??_USBSTOR#DISK&VEN_MYCOMPANY&PROD_ZZZZ_-_STORAGE&REV_5678#YYYY&0#{53F56307-B6BF-11D0-94F2-00A0C91EFB8B}"
Availability                :
Caption                     : Generic volume
ClassGuid                   : {71a27cdd-812a-11d0-bec7-08002be2092f}
CompatibleID                :
ConfigManagerErrorCode      : 0
ConfigManagerUserConfig     : False
CreationClassName           : Win32_PnPEntity
Description                 : Generic volume
DeviceID                    : STORAGE\VOLUME_??_USBSTOR#DISK&VEN_MYCOMPANY&PROD_ZZZZ_-_STORAGE&REV_5678#YYYY&0#{53F56307-B6BF-11D0-94F2-00A0C91EFB8B}
ErrorCleared                :
ErrorDescription            :
HardwareID                  : {STORAGE\Volume}
InstallDate                 :
LastErrorCode               :
Manufacturer                : Microsoft
Name                        : Generic volume
PNPDeviceID                 : STORAGE\VOLUME_??_USBSTOR#DISK&VEN_MYCOMPANY&PROD_ZZZZ_-_STORAGE&REV_5678#YYYY&0#{53F56307-B6BF-11D0-94F2-00A0C91EFB8B}
PowerManagementCapabilities :
PowerManagementSupported    :
Service                     : volsnap
Status                      : OK
StatusInfo                  :
SystemCreationClassName     : Win32_ComputerSystem
SystemName                  : BYDEFAULT

**GENUS                     : 2

__CLASS                     : Win32_PnPEntity

__SUPERCLASS                : CIM_LogicalDevice

__DYNASTY                   : CIM_ManagedSystemElement

__RELPATH                   : Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="USBSTOR\DISK&VEN_MYCOMPANY&PROD_ZZZZ_-_STORAGE&REV_5678\YYYY&0"

__PROPERTY_COUNT            : 24

__DERIVATION                : {CIM_LogicalDevice, CIM_LogicalElement, CIM_ManagedSystemElement}

__SERVER                    : BYDEFAULT

__NAMESPACE                 : root\cimv2

__PATH                      : \BYDEFAULT\root\cimv2:Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="USBSTOR\DISK&VEN_MYCOMPANY&PROD_ZZZZ_-_STORAGE&REV_5678\YYYY&0"

Availability                :

Caption                     : MYCOMPANY ZZZZ - Storage USB Device

ClassGuid                   : {4d36e967-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}

CompatibleID                : {USBSTOR\Disk, USBSTOR\RAW}

ConfigManagerErrorCode      : 0

ConfigManagerUserConfig     : False

CreationClassName           : Win32_PnPEntity

Description                 : Disk drive

DeviceID                    : USBSTOR\DISK&VEN_MYCOMPANY&PROD_ZZZZ_-_STORAGE&REV_5678\YYYY&0

ErrorCleared                :

ErrorDescription            :

HardwareID                  : {USBSTOR\DiskMYCOMPANY___ZZZZ_-_Storage5678, USBSTOR\DiskMYCOMPANY___ZZZZ_-*Storage, USBSTOR\DiskMYCOMPANY***, USBSTOR\MYCOMPANY___ZZZZ_-_Storage5...}
InstallDate                 :
LastErrorCode               :
Manufacturer                : (Standard disk drives)
Name                        : MYCOMPANY ZZZZ - Storage USB Device
PNPDeviceID                 : USBSTOR\DISK&VEN_MYCOMPANY&PROD_ZZZZ_-_STORAGE&REV_5678\YYYY&0
PowerManagementCapabilities :
PowerManagementSupported    :
Service                     : disk
Status                      : OK
StatusInfo                  :
SystemCreationClassName     : Win32_ComputerSystem
SystemName                  : BYDEFAULT

---

The above result set shows a lot of information.

Result 1 - 'SERVICE TYPE' is 'USBSTOR'. This is the Win32_PnPEntity I want to use when listening to '__InstanceModificaitionEvent' as it gives me the VID and PID.
Result 2 - Is the Composite Device representation which I am not interested in.
Result 3 - 'SERVICE TYPE' is 'volsnap'.  This is the volume entity and I am interested in this.
Result 4 - 'SERVICE TYPE' is 'disk'.  This is the disk entity and I am interested in this.

How do I get the relationship between 'Result 1' and 'Result 3' AND/OR 'Result 4'?

I have tried using the 'Win32_PnPDevice' associating class but it does not seem to get me to the point I need.  I am new to this powershell WMI and WMQ environment and so it is quite possible I am not using the 'Win32_PnPDevice' correctly.

I ran the following query to identify what was on the' SameElement' and 'SystemElement' properties of the relevant 'Win32_PnPDevice' entity:

> gwmi Win32_PNPDevice |%{[wmi]`(`$*.SameElement`)`} | select {$*.Name, $*.Description, $*.DeviceId, $_.Status}
>   gwmi Win32_PNPDevice |%{[wmi]`(`$*.SystemElement`)`} | select {$*.Name, $*.Description, $*.DeviceId, $_.Status}

The results can be read as follows:

> **Win32_PNPDevice.SameElement** - {PHYSICALDRIVE1, Disk drive,
>   PHYSICALDRIVE1, OK} 
>   **Win32_PNPDevice.SystemElement** - {MYCOMPANY ZZZZ - Storage USB Device,
>   Disk drive,
>   USBSTOR_DISK&VEN_MYCOMPANY&PROD_ZZZZ_-_STORAGE&REV_5678_YYYY&0,
>   OK}
>
> **Win32_PNPDevice.SameElement** - {USB Mass Storage Device, USB Mass Storage
>   Device, USB_VID_XXXX&PID_0001_YYYY,
>   OK}
>   **Win32_PNPDevice.SystemElement** - {USB Mass Storage Device, USB Mass
>   Storage Device,
>   USB_VID_XXXX&PID_0001_YYYY, OK}

Maybe I am using the 'Win32_PnPDevice' class incorrectly but it would seem that I can not connect the 'Win32_PnPEntity' to the 'Win32_DiskDrive'...

I hope this extra information better describes my issue.